# TextFieldParser ignoring header row C#

Tags: c#, csv, ssis

Reading in CSV files and the TextFieldParser skips the header row.

Any idea how to make certain the first row is skipped.

```
String[] Col3Value = new string[40];
TextFieldParser textFieldParser = new TextFieldParser(File1);
textFieldParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
textFieldParser.SetDelimiters(",");
{
    {
        string FileName = this.Variables.FileName.ToString();
        {
            while (!textFieldParser.EndOfData)         
            {
                File1OutputBuffer.AddRow();

               string[] values = textFieldParser.ReadFields();

               for (int i = 0; i <= values.Length - 1; i++)
               {
                   Col3Value[i] = values[i];

                   File1OutputBuffer.Column1 = Col3Value[0];
                   File1OutputBuffer.Column2 = Col3Value[1];
               }
           }
       }
   }
   textFieldParser.Close();
}
```

Comment: post the complete and correct code here.

Comment: With LINQ textFieldParser.ReadFields().Skip(1)

Comment: @PinBack Will  textFieldParser.ReadFields().Skip(1) work in C# ?

Comment: Skip works ... yes. using System.Linq; in your header.

Comment: You have to convert the output to an array: Skip(1).ToArray(); then you get string[]

Comment: @PinBack i just want to skip my header , but .skip(1) is deleting complete column 1 from the data

Comment: Ok. Then you have to skip the first row in your TextFieldParser. Without the code it is hard to find a solution.

Comment: the Above code is completely working , i just want to skip the 1st line of the file. @PinBack

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must manually skip first line.

Example from [Parsing a CSV file using the TextFieldParser](https://web.archive.org/web/20140402032134/https://mikesdotnet.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/parsing-a-csv-file-using-the-textfieldparser/)

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
{
    // set the parser variables
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters(",");

    bool firstLine = true;

    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        //Processing row
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

        // get the column headers
        if (firstLine)
        {
            firstLine = false;

            continue;
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Explicitly read the first line in an unparsed manner

```
if (!parser.EndOfData) {
    parser.ReadLine();
}

while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    var fields = parser.ReadFields();
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is a small performance benefit to this approach (read 1st line then read rest of file) compared to the other accepted approach (flag inside loop), because it omits the IF evaluation in the loop. For files with millions of lines, this tiny savings could add up.

Answer (score 6):

parser.LineNumber starts off as 1, so just continue after the first read.

```
while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    var fields = parser.ReadFields();

    if (parser.LineNumber <= 2) continue;
    
    ...
}
```